# CSS: Using multiple attributes

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Can I apply a style to an element using multiple attributes?

For example:
I want to apply a `display:block` rule to a div with a class of `aaa`
Unless it's wrapped in a div with a class of `bbb`

So I tried

```
[class~="aaa"] { display:none; }

[class~="bbb"][class~=“aaa"] { display:block; }
```

But that doesn't work. Is there a right way?

Comment: What does your HTML look like? Matching the same element with multiple attribute selectors is not the same as using attribute selectors on multiple different elements.

Answer (score 0):

For classes, you shouldn't be using [attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors). All you need are class selectors.

So, instead of:

```
[class~="aaa"] { display:none; }
```

you should have

```
div.aaa { display:none; }
```

Also, your [descendant selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) should have a space in it, so your second rule would be (not 100% sure about the exact syntax, though):

```
div.bbb div.aaa { display:block; }
```

Comment: I appreciate the input, but I don't think that's it, the first rule worked fine without the div tag. I just tried adding the div tag and it made no difference. And if I remove [class~="bbb"] from the 2nd line that rule overrides the first so I'm assuming the syntax is wrong.

Comment: @Bud Well, that would match _every_ element, not just div elements.

Comment: Your syntax is correct, barring the addition of the `div` selectors. Without them, it's `.bbb .aaa`.

Comment: OP specifically mentioned divs.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in Opera. (What browser are you using?)

**CSS**

```
[class~="aaa"] { color:red; }
[class~="bbb"] [class~="aaa"] { color:green }
```

Which (should be) logically equivalent to:

```
.aaa { color:red; }
.bbb .aaa { color:green }
```

**HTML**

```
<div class='aaa'>foo</div>
<div class='bbb'>
    <div class='aaa'>foo2</div>
</div>
```

**Please note:**

- (my code) the space between the two selectors in the second CSS line.
- (your code) your 5th double quote, was not the "proper" double quote.

**Example:** http://jsbin.com/hocir/1/edit?html,css,output

Comment: The incorrect quote is what's causing it to break. It should break properly across all browsers, because it results in invalid CSS.

Comment: I looked at it originally in FF. I'll add the space and see what happens when I revisit it later today. Thanks.

Comment: @Bud - Cool, check that double quote too!